# Problem when importing distributed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.6, distributed, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to import distributed version 1.22.0 installed with pip3.

However, I get this error :

```
    >>> import distributed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/distributed/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .core import connect, rpc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/distributed/core.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .system_monitor import SystemMonitor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/distributed/system_monitor.py", line 4, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/home/users/ej/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _pslinux as _psplatform
  File "/home/users/ej/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_linux as cext
ImportError: /home/users/ej/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_linux.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object
>>>
```

I have dask version 0.18.1 installed with pip3.

I work on Ubuntu 18.04 with python3.

I tried reinstall and install but no solution.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance.